# Laravel Validation for Requests - Dont let specific string pass

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ive written a form in Angular JS 2 which posts to a Laravel backend API and gets validated there also.. everything works as it should however if a field is left blank then when the user posts the form it is still written to the database as 'undefined'

is there anyway to class this string as empty using laravels rules ? my current rules file looks like this :

```
        <?php

        namespace App\Http\Requests;

        use App\Http\Requests\Request;

        class ContactFormRequest extends Request
        {
            /**
             * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
             *
             * @return bool
             */

            public function authorize()
            {
                return true;
            }

            public function rules()
            {
                return [
                    "name"    =>      "required|between:5,60",
                    "email"   =>      "required|between:5,60",
                    "website" =>      "required|between:5,60",
                ];
            }

            public function messages()
            {
                return [
                    'name.between'     => 'The :attribute must be between :min - :max.',
                    'name.required'    => 'The :attribute is required!',
                    'email.between'    => 'The :attribute must be between :min - :max.',
                    'email.required'   => 'The :attribute is required!',
                    'website.between'  => 'The :attribute must be between :min - :max.',
                    'website.required' => 'The :attribute is required!',
                ];
            }
        }
```

Comment: "when the user posts the form it is still written to the database as 'undefined'" => Does your Angular form still sends an empty field in the http request?

Comment: I would start checking what data is send from your Angular Script, looks like it sends the value 'undefined' if that field has not been filled by the user.

Comment: Yeah it was sending undefined to the api... I ended up solving it by creating a custom laravel validation rule that watched out for the work undefined and treated it as though it was an empty post request